# How to implement a multibranch tree structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, recursion, tree

I haven't written code in C for long time.
Im trying to do a multi-leaf tree.Im trying to convert a C# trie implementation to C in order to run it on GPU with CUDA.But i've stuck on this.Can you help me?

My node implementation as follows:

```
struct Node2 {
char *Key;
char *ConsAlterKey;
char *MasterKey;
bool VowelDeletion;
char *Data;
char *MasterData;
Node2 *Childs;
int ChildCount;
};
```

And here is my function that adds nodes to trie:

```
void AddAsChildren2(Node2 *Trie,int count)
{

//Trie->Childs=new Node2[count];
Trie->Childs=(Node2 *)malloc(sizeof(Node2)*count);

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    Trie->Childs[i].Key= GetKey();
    Trie->Childs[i].ConsAlterKey=GetConsAlterKey();
    Trie->Childs[i].MasterKey=GetMasterKey();
    Trie->Childs[i].VowelDeletion=GetVowelDeletion();
    Trie->Childs[i].Data=GetData();
    Trie->Childs[i].MasterData=GetMasterData();
    Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount=GetChildCount();

    if(Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount> 0)
    {
        AddAsChildren2(&(Trie->Childs[i]),Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount);
    }
}
}
```

which i call it from main function like this:

```
Node2 NodeNew;
    .
    .
    . 
AddAsChildren2(&NodeNew,NodeNew->ChildCount);
TraverseTree2(&NodeNew);
```

But when i try to traverse tree i get wrong values and sometimes exceptions.(Possibly memory allocation problem of child nodes)

What am i doing wrong here?

Ps:First node has child nodes and I have no problem with assigning values so ignore "getter" functions.I have changed them inorder to simplfy code.My problem is that i lose values after code completes this part.

Thanks for fast response.I read values from a file.

The structure of file looks like this.

**< Key ConsAlterKey MasterKey VowelDeletion Data MasterData ChildCount or >**

If a line/item has no child nodes it ends with ">" else it ends with ChildCount value.And here "-" character presents NULL value.

```
< root - - - - - 2
 < a - - False - - 4
  < aö - - False 184 - > 
  < dfı - - False 188 - > 
  < et ed - False 189 - 3 
   < aö - - False 184 - > 
   < dfı - - False 188 - > 
   < k ğ - False 191 - > 
  >
  < k ğ - False 191 - > 
 >
 < a - - False - - 4
  < aö - - False 184 - > 
  < dfı - - False 188 - > 
  < et ed - False 189 - 3 
   < aö - - False 184 - > 
   < dfı - - False 188 - > 
   < k ğ - False 191 - > 
  >
  < k ğ - False 191 - > 
 >
>
```

And not simplified version of my code as follows:

```
void AddAsChildren2(Node2 *Trie,FILE *fp,int count)
{

  char string[50];
  char *line=NULL;
  char *Temp;

  Trie->Childs=(Node2 *)malloc(sizeof(Node2)*count);
  //Trie->Childs=new Node2[count];


  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
if(fgets(string,50,fp))
{
        line=strtok(string," ");

    if(strcmp (line,"<")==0)
    {
        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].Key= (strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);

        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].ConsAlterKey=(strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);

        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].MasterKey=(strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);

        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].VowelDeletion=(strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);

        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].Data=(strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);

        line=strtok( NULL, " ");
        Trie->Childs[i].MasterData=(strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line);


        Temp = strtok( NULL, " ");

        if(strcmp(Temp,">")==0)
        {
                             //ends with >
            Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount=0;
        }
        else if((strcmp(Temp,"\n")!=0)&&(strlen(Temp)> 0))
        {
                           //ends with childcount value so it have childs

            Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount=atoi(Temp);

            AddAsChildren2(&(Trie->Childs[i]),fp,Trie->Childs[i].ChildCount);
        }


    }
}
```

}

}

Traverse function as follows:

```
void traversetree2(Node2 *tree)
{

printf("Key %s\n",tree->Key);
printf("ConsAlterKey %s\n",tree->ConsAlterKey);
printf("MasterKey %s\n",tree->MasterKey);

printf("Data %s\n",tree->Data);
printf("MasterData %s\n",tree->MasterData);

if(tree->ChildCount>0)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tree->ChildCount;i++)
    {
        traversetree2(&(tree->Childs[i]));
    }
}

}
```

And output is:

```
Key root
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
ConsAlterKey ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░÷E
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
ConsAlterKey
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
MasterData
Key ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
ConsAlterKey ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
MasterKey
Data ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠§E
MasterData
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code you've shown.  Are you also freeing the tries at some point?  Can you show the tracebacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, with more code it's easy:  Your problem is that `char string[50]` is a local variable and you save many pointers into this local array which is lost when `AddAsChildren2` returns.  Depending on whether you ever need to free this structure you could `strdup()` the whole line and then save the tokens from it or `strdup()` each individual token (to simplify freeing).

Comment: Thank you very much; i cant say how much i appreciate it.You saved me hours.

Comment: Forgive my newbie questions but i have one more to ask you.I have changed `Trie->Childs[i].Key= (strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":line)` to `Trie->Childs[i].Key= (strcmp(line,"-")==0?"":**strdup(line)**)`.After i assign this values to node's properties like this should i free them immediately? I mean should i use `LocalFree(line)` after each assignment?

Comment: No, just the `strdup(line)` is fine.  The challenge comes if you ever want to free the *entire* structure.  You can't free your literal `""` string.  Better to `strdup( cond ? "" : line )` so that every string is allocated and you can `free(Trie->Childs[i].Key)` if you ever dispose of the whole Trie.